# ERD files from Common Data Model - how to open? Erwin / PowerDesigner?

Tags: erd, datamodel, powerdesigner, erwin

I'm trying to access the ERD files here:
https://github.com/microsoft/Industry-Accelerator-Health/tree/master/documentation

Now, I would prefer to use a tool like PowerDesigner / Erwin to actually see the Physical Structure.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be related to the [NClass diagram editor](https://github.com/gbaychev/NClass)... which I did not know about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script which takes such an ERD model, and tries to create a PowerDesigner Object-Oriented Model from it. It is not complete and ignore some information, but it's a start.

To be run with `Tools > Execute Commands > Edit/Run Script` inside PowerDesigner.

```
option explicit
' load XML document
dim doc : set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
doc.load("C:\TEMP\Dynamics.365.Electronic.Medical.Records.erd")
' create model
dim model : set model = CreateModel(PdOOM.Cls_Model, "|Language=Analysis|Diagram=ClassDiagram")
dim diagram : set diagram = model.DefaultDiagram
' start entities enumeration
dim entities : set entities = doc.getElementsByTagName("Entity")
dim e, count
count = 0
dim mapent : set mapent = createobject("Scripting.Dictionary")
for each e in entities
   count = count+1
   dim name : name = "Class_" + cstr(count)
   dim n : set n = e.getElementsByTagName("Name")
   if n.length > 0 then
      name = n.item(0).firstChild.nodeValue
   end if
   dim p : set p = e.getElementsByTagName("Location")
   dim x,y
   if p.length > 0 then
      x = p.item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("left").nodeValue
      y = p.item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("top").nodeValue
   else
      x = 0
      y = 0
   end if
   dim c : set c = model.classes.CreateNew
   ' keep track of entity by number, to draw relationships
   mapent.add cstr(count),c
   c.setNameAndCode name,name
   dim sym : set sym = diagram.AttachObject(c)
   if x <> 0 and y <> 0 then
       'TODO check coordinates conversion, especially if autolayout is not called...
       dim pos : set pos = sym.position
       pos.x = x*50
       pos.y = y*50 - 20000
   end if
   ' add attributes
   dim atts : set atts = e.getElementsByTagName("Member")
   dim m
   for each m in atts
      if m.attributes.getNamedItem("type").nodeValue = "Field" then
         dim str : str = m.firstChild.nodeValue
         dim parts : parts = split(str,": ")
         dim att : set att = c.attributes.CreateNew
         att.setNameAndCode parts(0),parts(0)
         att.datatype = parts(1)
      end if
   next
next
' create relatonships
dim rels : set rels = doc.getElementsByTagName("Relationship")
dim r
for each r in rels
   dim first,second
   first = cstr(r.attributes.getNamedItem("first").nodeValue)
   second = cstr(r.attributes.getNamedItem("second").nodeValue)
   if not mapent.exists(first) then output "cannot find " + first
   if mapent.exists(first) and mapent.exists(second) then
      dim cf,cs
      set cf = mapent.item(first)
      set cs = mapent.item(second)
      dim a : set a = model.associations.createnew
      'TOOD check direction...
      set a.object1 = cf
      set a.object2 = cs
   end if
next

diagram.completelinks
diagram.autolayout
```

Comment: I extended the script a little, and put it in [github](https://github.com/pascalbaryton/PDThings/tree/master/Tools/nclass).

Comment: Hi Pascal, I ran this via the tools / execute run script and cut and paste the script from the vbs file and did not work.  I tried to run it standalone as well. Did not work either way..

Comment: Also, which version of PowerDesigner are you using, just in case?